# Two DOM elements with a single JavaScript event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have the following JavaScript:

```js
//for dom element 1//

$(document).on( 'click', '.dom1', function() {
   something;
});

//for dom element 2

$(document).on( 'click', '.dom2', function() {
   something;
});
```

Here I am using exactly the same piece of JavaScript for two different DOM elements, so how can I make them work under only one event handler, as both have same functionality?

I tried  using `||` but that didn't work.

```js
$(document).on( 'click', '.dom1' || 'dom2', function() {
   something;
});
```

Comment: A misleading title when using jQuery...

Answer (score 8):

Two ways to do that

One:

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.dom1, .dom2', function() {
   something;
});
```

Two:

```
function doSomething() {}
$(document).on( 'click', '.dom1', doSomething);
$(document).on( 'click', '.dom2', doSomething);
```

Comment: i think you meant `$(document).on( 'click', '.dom1, .dom2', function() {` instead of `$(document).on( 'click', '.dom1, .dom1', function() {` note the dom2